# Is "triple differences" and estimating "heterogeneous treatment effects" the same?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, terminology, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am running a difference-in-differences (DiD) regression with a time and treatment interaction and I have a continuous outcome variable. However, I hypothesize that the DiD estimator can be moderated by another variable, in this case a dummy which indicates political inclusion/exclusion.

However, I do not fully grasp the difference between the heterogeneous treatment effects (example: using covariate age and then interacting age (younger/older) with the DiD (i.e., $time \times treatment \times age$) and the triple DiD estimator whereby one has multiple dummy interactions and the DiDiD of interest (i.e., $time \times treatment \times dummy$).

While the former is often used in papers using the DiD method to give some insight into differences of the DiD among groups, the latter seems to be less frequently used.

Any clarification on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In both cases, the model is usually specified in the same way. In the former, we suspect one of the groups is more/less sensitive to the treatment. In the latter case, I suspect you’ve seen the author be a little more explicit, stating that there’s another “treatment group” at a lower level that’s worth investigating.

Comment: thank you for the clarification @ThomasBilach !

Comment: No problem. Did you read something in a paper that confused you? Please share the reference and I will offer a more detailed response.